# TRIGGER to calculate the total leaves of each left type group by employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have 2 tables like this

| EmployeeID | LeaveTypeID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |

Now I want a TRIGGER that calculate automatically total of type 1 and type 2 in below table

| EmployeeID | Type1 | Type2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: This is combining two bad ideas - in general, you shouldn't *store* that which can be *calculated*. Storing it just introduces opportunities for inconsistencies. Also, pre-pivoting the data means that you're embedding some of your data (1 & 2) into the *metadata* instead (as column names). Which means any time a new row (data) is added to one table (LeaveType) you are also forced to perform a DML operation to extend the table definition as well, and would have to re-write the trigger each time.

Comment: While you should consider the suggestions to change your approach, the better way of getting help is to try something first. Implement triggers is an advanced topic - are you ready for that? At a minimum, help is more likely if you write a basic "create trigger" statement even if it does nothing useful. A script containing DDL for your tables is also needed since no one knows what tables you have, what columns they contain, and what the primary keys are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for triggers. Just create a view that has the aggregation in it

```
CREATE VIEW vTotal
AS
SELECT
  t.EmployeeID,
  Type1 = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.LeaveTypeID = 1 THEN 1 END),
  Type2 = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.LeaveTypeID = 2 THEN 1 END)
FROM dbo.YourTable t
GROUP BY
  t.EmployeedID;
```